# unable to run the script

Tags: linux

```
d1=$(date --date="-10 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

d2=$(date --date="-1 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


sed -n "/$d1/,/$d2/p"  /tmp/samba.log

while read -r line; do
 if [[ $line -eq '- Exception from external service:' ]] ;

 then

    echo "Subject: Samba is Down "| /usr/sbin/sendmail -f rai@for.com
        -t xyz@cyient.com,
fi
done
```

Comment: At Least add the error that you get while trying to run the script.

Comment: Suspiciously similar to [Unable to get output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401339/80216) — this is almost certainly homework. [We don’t do people’s homework.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4206/80216)

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma at the end of the pipes at the echo. Renove that and it should be fine.